# How to create list of list by grouping on the basis of one list element using scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have following list structure-

```
List(("localhost","esx","192.168.1.1","33.36","93.80", "vms can not be added"),
 ("star","esx","192.168.1.2","62.61","47.20","vms can be added"),
 ("mars","esx","192.168.1.3","27.41","47.38","vms can be added), 
("moon","esx","192.168.1.4","23.58","69.40", "vms can not be added"))
```

I want following output -

```
List(("vms can be added",List(("star","esx","192.168.1.2","62.61","47.20"),
("mars","esx","192.168.1.3","27.41","47.38"))),

("vms can not be added",List(("localhost","esx","192.168.1.1","33.36","93.80"),
("moon","esx","192.168.1.4","23.58","69.40"))))
```

How do I get above output using scala???

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question is quite easy

```
val l=List(
  ("localhost","esx","192.168.1.1","33.36","93.80", "vms can not be added"),
  ("star","esx","192.168.1.2","62.61","47.20","vms can be added"),
  ("mars","esx","192.168.1.3","27.41","47.38","vms can be added"),
  ("moon","esx","192.168.1.4","23.58","69.40", "vms can not be added"))


l.groupBy(_._6).toSeq
```

which leads to this result:

```
ArrayBuffer(   
  (vms can not be added,
    List(
      (localhost,esx,192.168.1.1,33.36,93.80,vms can not be added), 
      (moon,esx,192.168.1.4,23.58,69.40,vms can not be added))),     
  (vms can be added,
     List(
       (star,esx,192.168.1.2,62.61,47.20,vms can be added), 
       (mars,esx,192.168.1.3,27.41,47.38,vms can be added))))
```

This is quite efficient, because it only changes the containing structures, but leaves the values intact.

If you really want to change the values, you can do this also quite easily, using the [Shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._

l.groupBy(_._6).mapValues(_.map(_.take(5))).toList
```

which gives you this:

```
List(   
  (vms can not be added,
    List(
      (localhost,esx,192.168.1.1,33.36,93.80), 
      (moon esx,192.168.1.4,23.58,69.40))),    
  (vms can be added,
    List(
      (star,esx,192.168.1.2,62.61,47.20), 
      (mars,esx,192.168.1.3,27.41,47.38))))
```

But you will change much more values and hence the pressure on the garbage collector will be higher. So you should only do this, when the additional value in each tuple is really a problem.

### Remark:

IntelliJ 14.0.1 gets some hickup with the shapeless expression above. It highlights the line as erroneous, but compiles (and runs) it quite fine.

Comment: For the bug in IntelliJ I have filed a bug report https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8035

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you need:

```
val res = list
  .map(t => (t._6, (t._1, t._2, t._3, t._4, t._5)))
  .groupBy(t => t._1)
  .mapValues(v => v.map(t => t._2))
  .toList

//    List(
//        (vms can not be added,
//         List(
//             (localhost,esx,192.168.1.1,33.36,93.80), 
//             (moon,esx,192.168.1.4,23.58,69.40))), 
//        (vms can be added,
//         List(
//             (star,esx,192.168.1.2,62.61,47.20), 
//             (mars,esx,192.168.1.3,27.41,47.38))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have binary categories, you can use `partition`:

```
val xs = List(("foo", "bar", 1), ("baz", "boing", 2), ("bla", "blub", 3))
val p = xs.partition(_._3 < 2)
```

...followed by a `map` to remove the key element:

```
val x0 = p._1.map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
val y0 = p._2.map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
```

Alternatively, use `filter`:

```
val x1 = xs.filter( _._3 <  2).map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
val y1 = xs.filter(!_._3 >= 2).map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
```

If the categories are not binary, you can use `groupBy` which gives you a `Map`, so you can then access the individual keys:

```
val m = xs.groupBy(_._3)
val x2 = m(1).map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
val y2 = m(2).map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
val z2 = m(3).map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this for comprehension,

```
for ( (k,v) <- myList.groupBy(_._6)) 
  yield k -> v.map ( x => (x._1,x._2,x._3,x._4,x._5) )
```

Also consider case classes that encapsulate the 6-tupled values for more readable references, instead of for instance  `x._5` . Namely,

```
case class Server(name: String,
                  x:    String,
                  ip:   String,
                  seg1: String,
                  seg2: String,
                  msg:  String)
```

and so we can then for instance `groupBy(msg)` and in the last `map`

```
map (x => x.copy(msg="") )
```

instead of referring to each and every parameter. Thus for

```
val myList = List( 
  Server("localhost","esx","192.168.1.1","33.36","93.80", "vms can not be added"),
  Server("star",...), ...)
```

we have that

```
for ( (k,v) <- myList.groupBy(msg)) yield k -> v.map (x => x.copy(msg="") )
```

**Update**

For converting lists of tuples to lists of case classes, consider this example that relies on invoking `tupled` method from a case class with a tuple as parameter,

```
val a = List( (1,2,"a"), (3,4,"b") )
a: List[(Int, Int, String)] = List((1,2,a), (3,4,b))

case class c(i:Int, j:Int, s:String)
defined class c

a.map(c.tupled(_))
res: List[c] = List(c(1,2,a), c(3,4,b))
```

Comment: Isn't your `for ... yield` basically doing `mapValues`?

Comment: @enzyme - I don't have case class.

Comment: @Vishwas, we know, Enzyme is suggesting you should! You can convert  your tuples to case classes with a `map`.

Comment: @Paul we need to provide the key in yield

Comment: @enzyme, that's OK, the original key is still there `myList.groupBy(_._6).mapValues(_.map(x => (x._1,x._2,x._3,x._4,x._5)))` produces the same output as your code

Answer (score 0):

I used following -

```
val myList = List(
("localhost","esx","192.168.1.1","33.36","93.80", "vms can not be added"),
("star","esx","192.168.1.2","62.61","47.20","vms can be added"),
("mars","esx","192.168.1.3","27.41","47.38","vms can be added), 
("moon","esx","192.168.1.4","23.58","69.40", "vms can not be added"))

myList.groupBy(_._6).map(x => (x._1,x._2.toList.map(p => 
("dnsName" -> p._1,"infrastructureType" -> p._2,
"hostId" -> p._3,"cpuUtilization" -> p._4, "memoryUtilization" -> p._5))))
```